# Prevent publishing ports defined in compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file that defines a service that will run my application and a service that that application is dependent on to run:

```
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - "../.:/opt/app"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - redis
    image: node
    command: ['yarn', 'start']
  redis:
    image: redis
    expose:
      - "6379"
```

For development this compose file exposes `8080` so that I can access the running code from a browser.

In jenkins however I can't expose that port as then two jobs running simultaneously would conflict trying to bind to the same port on jenkins.

Is there a way to prevent docker-compose from binding service ports? Like an inverse of the `--service-ports` flag?

---

For context:

In jenkins I run tests using `docker-compose run frontend yarn test` which won't map ports and so isn't a problem.

The issue presents when I try to run end to end browser tests against the application. I use a container to run [CodeceptJS](https://github.com/Codeception/CodeceptJS/) tests against a running instance of the app. In that case I need the frontend to start before I run the tests, as they will fail if the app is not up.

Comment: If `CodeceptJS` is a container, essentially you can add it to the compose file as a service and then for `frontend` service include `CodeceptJS` as 1 of the `links` candidate then use `expose` instead of `ports` to expose 8080 to the linked services. Will this work?

Answer (score 1):

> Q. Is there a way to prevent docker-compose from binding service ports?

It has no sense to prevent something that you are asking to do. `docker-compose` will start stuff as the `docker-compose.yml` file indicates.

I propose duplicate the `frontend` service using `extends:`:

```
version: "2"
services:
  frontend-base:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - "../.:/opt/app"
    image: node
    command: ['yarn', 'start']

  frontend:
    extends: frontend-base
    links:
      - redis
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  frontend-test:
    extends: frontend-base
    links:
      - redis
    command: ['yarn', 'test']

  redis:
    image: redis
    expose:
      - "6379"
```

So use it as this:

```
docker-compose run frontend         # in dev environment
docker-compose run frontend-test    # in jenkins
```

Note that `extends:` is not available in `version: "3"`, but they will bring it back again [in the future](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4315).

Comment: Clever approach, this sounds like the closest solution to having all this in one compose file and not needing to maintain two separate files.

Comment: But if there is a plenty of containers I start them with `docker-compose up` -- this does not allow me to specify one, not another.

Answer (score 0):

> **For preventing to publish ports outside the docker network you just
>   need to write on a single port in the ports segment.**

Instead of using this:

```
ports:
    - 8080:8080
```

Just use this one(at below):

```
ports:
    - 8080
```

Comment: Without specifying a HOST port, it randomly assigned, not prevented!
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports